# Restrict Word Wrap on a Specific Table Column With CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'd like to restrict word-wrap on the text in a single column of a table. Basically, I want the equivalent of `white-space: nowrap` on every cell in the second column of the table.

The thing is, I can't really access the html, only the CSS. So, is there a way to do this with CSS *only*?

EDIT: It really only needs to work with Chrome or most recent browsers.

Comment: Probably using `nth-child` but you'll run into browser compatibility issues (namely IE < 9 and FF up to 3). Can you live with that?

Comment: @Pekka: That would be just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`nth-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html) CSS 3 pseudo-class works in Chrome, FF > 3.0, and IE >= 9.

http://jsfiddle.net/TwcEB/

```
table tr > *:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

this is the only non-JavaScript way to do this.